# How can we check if an url is correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes

we have an app where the user get there own userspace an can create entries without login.
we generate an dynamic link
Like

```
localhost://apps/{owncode}/userspace
```

The owncode is calculated by us an the code will saved into the database

The user can add entries for his userspace.

```
localhost://apps/{owncode}/entries/new
```

How can I compare (check is its correct} the `{owncode}` from the database with the url. Because  we want to catch if someone call the url by try and error.

Comment: There are many ways to try to ferret out those sort of URLs, but we don't know enough about your system to really help. You could scan the database if you store the URLs the user generates, and look for pattern matches. You could scan their content, looking for the same sort of things. You could set up a trap in your HTTPd looking for certain combinations of source address and destination URL. All of them might work, but also have holes where a determined hacker/user could squeeze something through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check that without forcing the user to log in. You should also not be using anything in the URL to identify their "userspace." It should all be tucked away in the session, associated with the logged in user's account.

If you at least want to make `owncode` hard to guess, you could generate a ridiculously long hashed string. But this is not recommended, it would not guarantee any security, and users could still try and guess the strings for other "userspaces" without your app being able to do anything about it.

Comment: Do you know doodle.com? That app show the way how our app works (hopefully)

Comment: I'm not familiar, but I just set up a test event on it. Their site works with all the downsides that I just described in my answer. Someone can try to guess another user's secret URL. That's why their confirmation email asks the user to not send the admin link to anyone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought there is a way to check the url.